# ParseExcepion when trying to parse a string to a date in android

Tags: java, android, date, parse-error

i don't know what i'm doing bad. 
This is the exception that throws: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Fri Jun 14 13:25:40 ART 2013" (at offset 20)

And this is my code to parse the above string date to a object date:

```
    public static Date getDateParseFromString(String sDate){


        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(PARSE_DATE_PATTERN, Locale.getDefault());
        dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
        Date d = null;
        try {
            d = dateFormat.parse(sDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return d;
    }
```

The pattern is:

```
private static final String PARSE_DATE_PATTERN = "EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss z yyyy";
```

I see a lots of the issues related to this, but i can not found the problem with this, can help to me?

Thanks in advance.

Regards!

Comment: @ZouZou Since the offset is at 20, it seems to me like ART is not a known locale.

Comment: Oh yes is that, there is a default locale? Or this change depends the device configuration?

Comment: The `SimpleDateFormat` method will use your default `Locale` to parse the date string. Doing this, it knows that `Fri` refers to `Friday` and `Feb` refers to `February`. In this case, it seems that it doesn't know what to do with `ART`. It's possible the Java version you are using doesn't have that Argentina (?) time zone.

Comment: @user1977204 The default Locale is the user's preferred locale. Not a default one that everybody have (if I understand your comment). You get the Locale selected on the device when your app is launched. So yes, this depends on the device configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers, the problem is the Locale.
I explain with a little more details what i do for this error. This dates i downloading from the parse.com repository app, and then put the data in a SQLLite DB for export the .apk with the basic data that have in the repository.
Then when a user run the app i have a process that execute an update from this repository, and the problem is that my initial data i have is in Argentina timezone, so if a user in other place in the world dont have this Locale installed in their device the app will crash.
So for fix this error my team decided to pass the date obtained from the repository to a millisecond using `the getTime()` method from the Date class.

Then comparing with a millisecond date that save when export the .apk if have any updates from the repository.

Thanks again!

Regards!

Comment: You could delete your question then, I'm not sure if it's really add a valuable information to this site (no offense intented) :-)

Comment: or take the time to make an actual answer

Comment: @ZouZou, I think this it is plausible that someone else could have the same problem and find help here. The answer could be improved, however.

Comment: @PaulDraper Well I see a lot of similar questions that had the same problem because they used (implicitely or not) the default Locale. Anyway, if this answer stays like that, there is no need to keep this question. And yes if the OP explained well what was the problem and how he corrected that, I do agree that it should be kept.

Comment: @ZouZou, if you do see a duplicate, mark it accordingly.